# Vagrant error with apache on virtual box and puphpet

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, puphpet

I try to install a virtual machine on my Windows 10, but I get this error when I do my "vagrant up" :

> Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could
>   not find any files from C:/Users/[user_name]/Sites/ at
>   /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-75f35e3bc7e32744860c4bb229c88812/Apache.pp:214:18
>   on node dev.local

I have the last version of Virtual Box and Vagrant and I generate my Vagrantfile with Puphpet.

Some idea ? 
Thank's a lot !

There is my config.yaml :

```
    vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/debian75-x64
                box_url: puphpet/debian75-x64
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        use_linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_l3tmsdnqbkla:
                        id: dev.local
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.56.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                vflmnfp_uyuz402guweb:
                                    host: '9864'
                                    guest: '22'
                        hostname: dev.local
                        memory: '512'
                        cpus: '1'
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_ky6d7w9y7kcw:
                source: 'C:\Users\Francois\Sites'
                target: /var/www/dev.local
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
            vflsf_00l442nxer10:
                source: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-1'
                target: /var/www/dev.local/site-1
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
            vflsf_ysyvamrm0crp:
                source: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-2'
                target: /var/www/dev.local/site-2
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: 'false'
        port: 'false'
        private_key_path: 'false'
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: 'false'
        keep_alive: '1'
        forward_agent: 'false'
        forward_x11: 'false'
        shell: 'bash -l'
        insert_key: 'false'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
    proxy:
        http: ''
        https: ''
        ftp: ''
        no_proxy: ''
        enabled: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: en_US.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
        timezone: UTC
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_s1omdcroka8m:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_mh4ktofvpbtb:
                    location: /
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_pdudf100a2or:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: 2.4
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_suhjjehs6wnr:
            servername: dev.local
            serveraliases:
                - www.dev.local
            docroot: /var/www/dev.local
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/'
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_kdbe5ebbiivu:
                    path: /var/www/dev.local
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/'
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_62cqz47jox0c:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/'
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
        av_q6d203nniemz:
            servername: site-1.local
            serveraliases:
                - www.site-1.local
                - '*.site-1.local'
            docroot: /var/www/dev.local/site-1
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-1'
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_m6ipc7e85vdf:
                    path: /var/www/dev.local/site-1
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-1'
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_0zxwp9mdlar3:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-1'
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
        av_lmhvtyhkh2oc:
            servername: site-2.local
            serveraliases:
                - www.site-2.local
            docroot: /var/www/dev.local/site-2
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
                - 'APP_ENV_DEV fc'
            custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-2'
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_57i55nxqyjc8:
                    path: /var/www/dev.local/site-2
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-2'
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_ozvvgf81rsa6:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: 'C:/Users/Francois/Sites/site-2'
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_dnbosrzxcrwp:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '1'
    version: v0.21.1
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        rv_6v3oqajqezb5:
            version: 1.9.3
            gems:
                - deep_merge
                - activesupport
                - vine
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '5'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mariadbnu_914l7r9bvpnm:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_mrrwnoruonm0:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_l1dv9a496dgc:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.5'
        root_password: root
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users: {  }
    databases: {  }
    grants: {  }
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.4'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    globals:
        version: 2.6.0
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailhog:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '8025'
        path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 2.1.0
        java_install: true
    instances:
        esi_lfg5oh0c5qji:
            name: es-01
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Comment: It looks like your actual username is not in the file path shown... `C:/Users/[user_name]/Sites/`

Comment: It's only for example, I have de real user name in my path. But thank's...

Comment: Please edit with your config.yaml and ping me!